# How to get the second occurrence of a condition on pine script

Tags: pine-script, trading

I have a strategy in tradingview that enters every time this condition is true, but I only need to enter the second occurrence of this condition

```
LongCondition = (wasOverSold and crossoverBull) and up_trend == false
```

[image]

the `LongCondition` gets true only on the exact candle where the blue cross appears (macd crossover), after that it is gets false all the time.

I already have tried using the history-referencing operator `enter = LongCondition[1] ? true : false` but it just delays the buy entry.

how can i find that second occurrence every time after an enter exit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a counter for that. Increase it when your condition becomes `true`, check if it is 2, enter position and reset your counter for next order.

Here is an example that enters and exits position whenever a MACD cross takes place the second time.

```
//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

n = input.int(2, "Number of occurences")

var bullCrossCnt = 0
var bearCrossCnt = 0

[macdLine, signalLine, histLine] = ta.macd(close, 12, 26, 9)

bullCross = ta.crossover(macdLine, signalLine)
bearCross = ta.crossunder(macdLine, signalLine)
bullCrossCnt := bullCross ? bullCrossCnt + 1 : bullCrossCnt
bearCrossCnt := bearCross ? bearCrossCnt + 1 : bearCrossCnt

if (bullCross and bullCrossCnt == n)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    bullCrossCnt := 0  // Reset variable

if (bearCross and bearCrossCnt == n)
    strategy.close("Long")
    bearCrossCnt := 0  // Reset variable
```

[image]